# Whether to use the plural "sind" or the singular "ist"?

Tags: grammatical-number

> Das hier **sind** bestimmt die Ruinen der Stadt.
>
> Das hier **ist** bestimmt die Ruinen der Stadt.

I'm not sure which I should consider to be the subject of this sentence: the singular "das" or the plural "Ruinen".

Answer (score 1):

In deinem Beispiel ist die Antwort klar. Dein Beispiel *"Das ist die Ruinen der Stadt"* ist in jedem Falle falsch. Es muss heißen

> Das **sind** die Ruinen der Stadt.

Prädikat und Subjekt müssen stets den gleichen Numerus tragen (Singular oder Plural), und als Subjekt gilt hier *die Ruinen*. Ein Demonstrativpronomen wie *das* gilt nicht als Subjekt eines solchen Satzes.

Das ist im Deutschen etwas strikter als im Englischen, wo man auch "That's the ruins of the city" hören kann oder etwas wie "Everybody [sing.] should check if their [plur.] luggage is stored safely".

Es gibt allerdings Fälle von Konflikten bei der Kongruenz von Prädikat und Subjekt, wo zwei Lesarten berechtigt sein können.

> Essen und Trinken halten Leib und Seele zusammen.
>
> Essen und Trinken hält Leib und Seele zusammen.

Hier sind beide Varianten möglich, jenachdem ob man Essen und Trinken als zwei Tätigkeiten auffasst oder als eine einzige Tätigkeit (ausgedrückt durch "Essen und Trinken").

Eine Liste ähnlicher Konfliktfälle ist [auf dieser Website](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Schwierigkeiten_bei_der_Kongruenz) publiziert.[1](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Schwierigkeiten_bei_der_Kongruenz) Man lernt daraus, dass es manchmal wirklich schwierig ist. Beim Schreiben wäre ein guter Rat, Satzkonstruktionen, die zu Kongruenzkonflikten führen, besser zu vermeiden.

> Du und deine Freunde fahren gerne an den Baggersee.

Solche Sätze kann man im Alltag oft hören. Für die Schriftsprache sind sie problematisch, da unschön. Eine saubere Lösung wäre

> Du und deine Freunde, ihr fahrt gerne an den Baggersee.

---

[1](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Schwierigkeiten_bei_der_Kongruenz) Nota bene:

> Eine Liste ähnlicher Konfliktfälle **ist** hier publiziert

nicht

> <strike>Eine Liste ähnlicher Konfliktfälle **sind** hier publiziert.</strike>

---

PS: a similar question - and interesting answers - are to be found [on this page of the Stackexchange French language forum](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25949/accord-dans-le-point-fort-de-cette-application-sont-ses-exercices)

Comment: Note that in English "everybody -> their" is not a sloppy number mismatch, but a gender neutral phrasing.

Comment: (Keyword "singular they", frequently discussed on our sister site English Language Learners.)